# Как объединить 2 файла построчно в Sublime

Tags: sublime-text

Как объединить в sublime text или любом другом редакторе 2 файла так, чтобы объединились 1 строка 1 го файла 1 строка 2 го файла и т.д

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сделал так. В первом файле:

1. Через поиск с учетом регулярных выражений (это кнопка с иконкой "`.*`") находим все окончания строк (В поиске указать символ `$`)
2. Выделяем их все (`find all` или `alt+enter`)
3. Нажимаем `shift+home` чтобы выделилась целиком строка (кажется надо будет отключить перенос строк). Копируем в буфер.

Во втором файле:

Пункты 1 и 2 так же как в первом файле. 
Вставляем из буфера (можно предварительно пробел поставить или таб, или тот разделитель который вам нужен).

Comment: У меня почему-то не получилось: все сделал как нужно, курсоры появляются, в буфер скопировал - вставляю, а там только первая строка нормально встает, остальные просто заменяются на содержимое строк 2 файла

Comment: А количество строк в файлах одинаковое? Вы делаете так чтобы и в первом и во втором файле появились множественные курсоры?

Comment: Исправил ответ на немного другую последовательность действий, смысл практически тот же.